# What is the name of the default style for matplotlib 2.0.0?

Tags: python, matplotlib

The default style of `matplotlib 2.0` looks very different from all previous versions.

I know that I can switch to the classic style with `mpl.style.use('classic')`, but how do I switch back to the new `v2.0` style?
Is the name of new default style listed in `matplotlib.style.available` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Per the [API documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/style_api.html):

> The style name of `default` is reserved for reverting back to the default style settings.

In my distribution, `'default'` is not listed in `matplotlib.style.available`, nor is it a key in `matplotlib.style.library`.

Comment: Thanks! The fact that the `default` style is not in `matplotlib.style.available` was a bit confusing.

Answer (score 9):

After having applied a style in matplotlib, you can switch back to the defaults by

```
plt.rcParams.update(plt.rcParamsDefault)
```

If this happens inside a jupyter notebook, you would then also need to recall the backend, e.g. `%matplotlib inline`.